# Squaring a complex exponential that represents a real number

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

Often, complex exponential functions are used to represent trigonometric functions, since

$$
e^{i\theta} \equiv \cos\theta + i\sin\theta .
$$

Thus, if for example I want to express the quantity $\cos x$, I might write:

$$
\cos x \equiv \Re\left\{e^{i x}\right\} .
$$

I'm told that I can manipulate the LHS just like I would the RHS, and at the end just take the real part to get the same answer as other methods, but I have come across some trouble.

Let's say I wanted to square the LHS to get $\cos^2 x$. On the RHS, this would give me:
$$
\begin{align}
e^{2ix} &= (\cos x + i \sin x)^2 \\
         &= (\cos^2x - \sin^2 x + 2i\cos x \sin x) \\
\implies \Re\{e^{2ix}\}         &= \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x
\end{align}
$$

Now, of course I recognise that the RHS is the identity for $\cos 2x$, which makes complete sense since $e^{2ix} \equiv e^{i(2x)}$. My question then is, why do the rules suddenly break down as soon as I attempt to square my complex exponential as I would my trig function? And what are the most conventional steps to take to work around this? Many thanks.

Comment: Something, something, branch cuts. Exponentiation is a multivalued thing in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @SeanRoberson No, exponentiation is **not** multivalued.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ah, I think Sean's probably thinking of logarithms then

Comment: @jumbot Yes, perhaps.

Comment: "My question then is, why do the rules suddenly break down as soon as I attempt to square my complex exponential as I would my trig function?"  Could you explain and give an example where it "breaks down".  So far as I can tell you example shows it works just fine.

Comment: @jumbot The real part $\Re$ does not commute with multiplication. You could write $a = \Re z$ as $a = \frac {z+\bar z}{2}$ instead, then square that equality.

Comment: .... but of course  $Re (z^k) \ne (Re z)^k$, if that what you are talking about......

Comment: @fleablood yes, indeed, that's what I meant by 'breaks down'.

Comment: You are comparing two different equations. For 1) $\cos x = Re(e^{ix})$ thensquaring both side gives you $\cos^2 x = (Re(e^{ix}))^2$  which is certainly true.  But then your example give another equation altogether $e^{ix} = \cos x + i\sin x$ and $e^{i2x} = (\cos x + i\sin x)^2= (\cos^2x -\sin^2 x) + 2i\cos x\sin x$ and $R((e^{ix})^2)=\cos^2x - \sin^2 x$ which is also true.  But they are two different completely different results from different equations.

Comment: Bear in mind   $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2$.  It's not true for reals and it's still not true for complex.  If $z = Re(z) + iIm(z)$ it does not follow that $z^2 = Re^2(z) + iIm^2(z)$.

Comment: @fleablood ok, thanks. I guess I'd just never really considered the $\Re$ operator as anything more than a couple of brackets, and evidently that was the wrong way to consider it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you cannot deduce from $a=\operatorname{Re}(z)$ that $a^2=\operatorname{Re}(z^2)$, which is what you did. For instance, $1=\operatorname{Re}(1+i)$, but $1^2\ne\operatorname{Re}\bigl((1+i)^2\bigr)=0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what is the typical way to deal with exponents when using complex numbers to represent real ones?

Comment: There is no general rule, since the map $z\mapsto\operatorname{Re}(z)$ does not behave well with respect to multiplication and exponentiation.

Comment: Cool, so just convert it back to real numbers, do the exponentiation, and then put it back into the complex plane if necessary? Sounds like a plan. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This problem often comes up when dealing with [analytic signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_signal), eg in electromagnetism. We only measure real electric and magnetic fields, but it is easier to manipulate complex expressions and only take the real part at the end. For many calculations this is ok, especially when taking time averages of things that oscillate sinusoidally with time, but this exact problem crops up when we try to use the analytic signal to calculate correlation functions that involve products of multiple electric and magnetic fields.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic In those domains, you're actually considering complex sequences or functions as a vector space over $\Bbb R$, so addition and (real) scalar multiplication are the allowed operations. In this framework, $\Bbb C$ is essentially just $\Bbb R^2$, and the Euler formula is used to "convert" between these vectors and true complex values.

Comment: @AlexJones I agree, just mentioning that being unaware of the pitfalls of this mapping leads to similar mistakes when trying to take products of the functions in such contexts.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of the title is incorrect, and that may be the source of the confusion. When we write

$$ \exp(it) = \cos t + i\sin t \in \Bbb C$$

this is *not* a complex number representing a real number. It is a complex number representing *two* real numbers.

A complex number representing *one* real number would be written as

$$ \exp(ik\pi) = a + i\cdot 0 \in \Bbb C $$

and these numbers multiply and square as you would expect.

On the other hand, if you want compound numbers that represent two real numbers, like

$$ (a,b)\in \Bbb R^2 $$

then the only way to have multiplication (and exponentiation) preserve both values is to have a componentwise multiplication like the Hadamard product. On the other hand, $\Bbb C$ is differentiated from other structures on $\Bbb R^2$ *precisely* by its multiplication, which must have

$$(0,1)\cdot (0,1) = (-1,0) \neq (0,1)$$

and is therefore not componentwise.

For this particular example, the fact that

$$ \exp((0,1)\cdot t) = (\cos t,\sin t) $$

holds at all is actually a result of the definition of complex multiplication. For $\Bbb R^2$ with a Hadamard product, we have

$$ \exp((0,1)\cdot t) = (0,\exp t) $$

while for dual numbers (which have $(0,1)\cdot (0,1) = 0$), we have

$$ \exp((0,1)\cdot t) = (1,t) $$

Interestingly, dual numbers actually *do* preserve the first component ("real part") through multiplication (and exponentiation), because

$$ (a,x)\cdot (b,y) = (ab,ay+bx) $$

so it is possible to preserve one coordinate without componentwise multiplication, but the product on $\Bbb C$ doesn't do this.